# Match pattern and populate csv file

Tags: python-3.x

Trying to open a file and search each line for a string.  If string is matched, I want to write "pass" or "fail" to CSV file.  Below code is not working.  Please assist.

```
import re
path = 'C:/mypath'
fh = open("C:/report.csv", "w+")
print('Device Name', 'Compliance Check 1', sep=",", file=fh)

for filename in os.listdir(path):
    with open(os.path.join(path,filename), "r") as infile:
        for line in infile:
            if re.match('some string'):
                check1 = 'pass'
            fh.write("{},{}\n".format(filename, check1))
fh.close()
```

Comment: In what way is the code not working? Throwing an error, producing no output, the wrong output?

Comment: No output produced.

Comment: sorry, figured out why no output was produced.  Now I'm getting "TypeError: match() missing 1 required positional argument: 'string'

Comment: `re.match` takes atleast 2 arguments, the pattern and the string which to be matched against. So where is your string?

Comment: Here's what I have now.  Output is writing "pass" for all of the files, but it should not.  for filename in os.listdir(path):
    with open(os.path.join(path,filename), "r") as infile:
        for line in infile:
            if re.match("logging buffered", line):
                check1 = 'pass'
        fh.write("{},{}\n".format(filename, check1))
fh.close()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be 
`result = re.match(pattern, string)`

So in this case `re.match('some string', line)`

If you aren't using regex you can just do `line.startswith('some string')`

Also, you don't set a value for check1 if there isn't a match and don't reset the value for each line.

I believe you just want to write "pass" or "fail" once per file so I unindented that.

```
import re
path = 'C:/mypath'
fh = open("C:/report.csv", "w+")
print('Device Name', 'Compliance Check 1', sep=",", file=fh)

for filename in os.listdir(path):
    with open(os.path.join(path,filename), "r") as infile:
        check1 = 'fail'
        for line in infile:
            if re.match('some string', line):
                check1 = 'pass'
        fh.write("{},{}\n".format(filename, check1))
fh.close()
```